# Ipad displaying UIUserInterfaceIdiomiPhone instead of UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have developed an universal app which is working fine in our iphone and ipad. But the app is displaying iphone UI in one of the other ipad. That ipad is jailbroken and the iOS version is 4.3.2. For checking this I have added an alert inside the condition 'if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)'. Which always return UIUserInterfaceIdiomiPhone instead of UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad in that ipad.

how to solve this issue? Any help is appreciated..

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

If this doesn't work:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {...}
```

Then you should try changing the target's build configuration: Make sure that "**Targeted Device Family**" is set to "**iPhone/iPad**".

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Did you install RetinaPad?..
Sugegstion: update to a new version (4.3.3) and JB again

Answer (score 0):

That certainly has something to do with the device being jail-broken. `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` is one of the most highly used APIs and works absolutely fine.